is it possible to sql query and combine data from very different sources like mysql, json storage, document db into 1 table?
Is there tool that can abstract away drastically different data formats - graph database, sql and mongodb, json document and combine them and output into 1 table?

no, you need to store all data in one daatabase, or use python C# to grab the data and combine it and finally save it wherever you need

Even if there were, it would be so complex to use that you'd be better off writing your own application code to query each data source and combine the results in the way you want.

Multiple "tables" in one "database" is the normal way to do things.  Elaborate on what you need.
